# PHP performance strpos filename or MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, strpos

I'm storing some highres files on a serves (100K+ if that matters) and I organize them in different galleries. When somebody access the gallery I only show thumbnails and a lowres version of the images, which in some cases is watermarked in other case not. Now due to the fact that I'm speaking of a huge amount of pictures the low resolution version which is displayed on the gallery page is purged from the server after X days. If somebody does access the gallery and the lowres version of the file doesn't exist on the server it is generated on the fly, however when I generate the lowres I might need to watermark it or not.

Currently, the script which display the images doesn't do any SQL call it's all based on filesystem (if file exists, etc) and the decision to watermark an image or not is based on:

```
if (strpos($file_name,"FREE")===false){ //add watermark }else{ //just resize}
```

My logic says this is more performant than doing an SQL query against the filename or fileid and checking if it should be a non watermarked image. However I find it a bit of inconvenience to have the file names containing the word FREE.

How much of a performance difference I can expect if I use an SQL query instead of the strpos?

**EDIT/UPDATE**

To summarize up the answers and the comments:

- The system is being designed to be working for a few years, with all the galleries which are added over time to be still accessible. This means the storage requirement is just HUGE, and older albums high res image will be moved off-site on slow and cheap dedicated storage, so suggestion to keep an additional overhead off all the thumbnails it's a severe no go option. Last year I needed to store over 3TB of images (this is only the highres size).
- I'm on Lighttpd and I'm intending to use `rewrite-if-not-file` to get the best performance for the existing thumbnails.
- I know about the I/O write penalty and I intend to keep it to the minimum, writing only when necessary, preferably reading. However the comment from @N.B. did actually got me thinking to store the lowres images on an SSD, so even when I need to create and write them to the disk have a much better I/O performance than a normal HDD.
- It will be actually difficult to do some test (@Steve E.) I'm behind schedule and the system has to go live by the end of this month. (I just got the bomb today that they are pulling the plug on the old system). Yes the flexibility is the main reason I'm tempted to go with SQL, but I'm expecting the SQL database to grow significantly, beside the file information, there are loads of other informations that I need to store as well, tagging, purchases, downloads, etc, so I'm also trying to make sure that I'm not putting too much pressure on the SQL, when I can actually leverage some of that with a good structure and Filesystem access.

Comment: Where is the 'FREE' tag takes place in the file name? If you really want to avoid SQL queries, you can still use memcached, or other KV stores for cacheing, or put the tag to a specific position in the file name or path.

Comment: Your performance penalty comes form writing to the disk, not from dealing with a file name. Whether you use MySQL, filesystem or anything else, your script will be slow once it starts writing to the disk. Therefore, whatever software you might use, your constraining factor will be I/O capability of the drive that does the work. This is yet another XY problem, you're asking for an advice between two approaches which, in your mind, yield a solution, but the real problem is completely elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without doing tests, it is hard to be certain which approach would be faster. Simple logic may suggest that PHP accessing disk is faster, but that is based on a lot of assumptions.

In a well configured system, variables that are required frequently will be in the RAM cache rather than on disk. This applies to caching of the filesystem as well as MySQL caching indexes. The impact of caching and other mechanisms can give results different to what might be expected.

In many scenarios, either solution will work and be adequate since the time taken for either request should be minimal in a well designed system and the extra performance of one approach may not be worth the inconvenience you find with using 'FREE' in the filename. It would not be too hard to trial both methods and measure performance.

In the long term also consider that MySQL provides more flexibility for adding additional functionality that would get complicated if all the state was stored in file names.

If performance really is a significant issue, then look at using the webserver to check for the file on disk (or in a cache like memcache) and return that if it exists before passing the request to PHP at all. Both Nginx and Apache can do this, it's a common acceleration approach for high traffic websites.

Answer (score 1):

You've already done the hard part. SQL query in your case will only slow you down...

here's how you're doing it

```
user--->php-->filesystem-->php--->user
```

if mysql comes in this is how it goes

```
user--->php--->mysql--->filesystem--->mysql-->php--->user
```

so you're already saving yourself some time while not using mysql...

Comment: Each option you mentioned might get worst if OP coded it wrong

Comment: indeed, but in this case it's not coded wrong, because as he said, he keeps images in galleries (so I assume he means separate folders), so the op didn't code it wrong?

Comment: Yeap separate folder structures, per year, per album, etc, and parameters to the GET parameters of the script are used to display/generate the thumbnails. Thanks, I head the same logic...

Answer (score 1):

> If somebody does access the gallery and the lowres version of the file doesn't exist on the server it is generated on the fly

If the highres versions are not stored in a database but as server files, this means that the low res thumbnails occupy very little space in proportion to the high res images. For example, lets assume the low res images are 10% of the size of the high res ones. Keeping **all** the low res images available on your server only adds 10% to your storage needs and if you haven't got 10% spare capacity, then you need to go shopping for more storage, not try programming workarounds.

From the comment, it appears you already store some information about the file in the database. If this is the case then you should be able to add a column to determine if it is free or not and get the extra column at the same time as you query for the other info, adding little to no overhead.

Comment: No no, not storing so much binary data in tables that will be pure suicide :) I only store file related information (file name, folder name, file creation date) in SQL. Very little is relative when you deal with a turn around of about 800K images in a year.

Comment: So you have lots of high res images on a fileserver. You may as well generate all the low res images because that would only add 10% (nominal) to your disk storage and if you haven't got 10% capacity spare you need to go shopping for more storage.

Comment: Edited original answer based on your comment